# DRF TypeError __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I get this error when I try to make a GET request via my web browser.
 It's my first DRF project and I try to make a api to be able to use it on a mobile app. I think the problem comes from the get I made in my views.py
Here's some code snippets and the Traceback:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Expediteur(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tel = models.IntegerField()
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import Expediteur, Destinataire, LettrePrio, TypeLettreReco, LettreReco, TimbrePrio, TimbreReco


class ExpediteurSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Expediteur
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import viewsets, status, HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from api.serializers import ExpediteurSerializer, DestinataireSerializer, LettrePrioSerializer, TypeLettreRecoSerializer, LettreRecoSerializer, TimbrePrioSerializer, TimbreRecoSerializer
from api.models import Expediteur, Destinataire, LettrePrio, TypeLettreReco, LettreReco, TimbrePrio, TimbreReco

import json
import datetime

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, Http404
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView

# Create your views here.

class ExpeViewSet(APIView):
    queryset = Expediteur.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExpediteurSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        if request.GET.get("id"):
            queryset = Expediteur.objects.filter(id=request.GET["id"]).all()
        else:
            queryset = Expediteur.objects.all()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def list(self,request):
          queryset  = self.Expediteur.objects.all()
          serializer = ExpediteurSerializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True)
          return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.DATA)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from rest_framework import routers
from django.contrib import admin
import api

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'CUP.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', 'api.views.ExpeViewSet'),
)
```

**traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/expediteur/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'api')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/expediteur/
Exception Value: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Please show your urls.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman just edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't create urls like that. ApiView is a class, you need to use the  `as_view` classmethod and refer to the class directly, not as a string:

```
url(r'^api/', api.views.ExpeViewSet.as_view()),
```

Comment: I know that the name I give doesn't make my class a ViewSet, but what did I make wrong and how could I fix this ?

Comment: Sorry, that answer was misleading, I have replaced it.

Comment: thanks for your help, I just fixed it, but now I have an AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute 'views', is there anything wrong in my imports ?